# how to load objfile in vue (three.js)

Tags: vuejs2

ERROR in ./src/assets/objFile/testfile.obj 1:12

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:12)

You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.

```
import as THREE from 'three'
import { OBJLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader"
import objAddress from '../src/assets/objFile/testfile.obj'



mounted(({
    console.log(this,address)
    let scene = new THREE.Scene()
    let renderer = new THREE.WebGL1Renderer({
        canvas : document.querySelector('#canvas')
})

let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30,1);
camera.position.set(0,0,0)

let loader = new OBJLoader() 
loader.load(objAddress,function(obj){
  scene.add(obj,scene)
  renderer.render(scene,camera)
})
},
};
```

Comment: What format is that obj file?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Vite:

```js
import objAddress from '../src/assets/objFile/testfile.obj?url'
```

If you use Webpack:

- add `rules` to `webpack.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.obj$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 8192,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

if you're using something else tell me i'll add it